# Using Entity Framework 5 with overloaded Oracle stored procedures

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures, odp.net

I have the following question.

I have a couple of stored procedures in an Oracle database package. As it is, they differ in the number of parameters (I'm not allowed to touch or change the stored procedures).

I was using ODP.NET and Entity Framework 5, with EntLib.Contrib.Data to manage access and manipulation of this database:

```
Database db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>();
...
using( var reader = db.ExecuteReader("SP_NAME", parameters[])
{
     ...
}
```

I HAVE to use parameter discovery because our framework is designed that way. Changing it is the last resource.

I have been able to get access to SPs and functions using this method, but a problem arises when I try to to execute a SP that has an overload. Namely, an exception is thrown that I am not sending the right number of parameters to execute that SP. Only one of them is accessible (the one that was declared first in the package): the second throws this exception all the time.

I tried passing the parameters one by one, in a List {}, in an object[], using ExecuteDataSet(), but it hasn't worked.

Is there any way to make it happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Entity Framework with Oracle... you poor thing.

Comment: Why? Is it a lost cause?

Comment: Well... The EF driver from Oracle is really, really bad. I used the comercial DevArt driver, which was okay, but still a lot of work to work around the quirks.

Comment: This is completely unrelated to EF - you are not using EF to execute your stored procedure. Your question is only related to features offered by ODP.NET.